# Applying rules dynamically in Python

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

I've currently written a small python application, that lets me log temperature data from a few different sensors, and save it to a MySQL database. Now I want to do something useful with that data, by using rules. These rules should be dynamic, so I am always able to change them through a web interface I'm developing.

The problem is, that I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this, saving rules to a database and then using them in Python. Lets have an example:

`TURN ON LIGHT 1: IF SENSOR1 > x and SENSOR2-SENSOR3 > y`

Where x and y are variables. I think where I've gone wrong is in my chosen datastructure. My sensors are structured as objects in a list like so:

```
import os
tempSensors = []

def initializeSensors():

    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/sys/bus/w1/devices/'):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            sensorID = subdirname
            if sensorID != 'w1_bus_master1':
                tempSensors.append(Sensor(sensorID))
```

And the sensor class:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MySQLdb
import time
from pathlib import Path

class Sensor:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.temperature = 0
        self.timestamp = 0

    def temp(self, timestamp):
        sensorPath = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/%s/w1_slave' % self.id

        if Path(sensorPath).is_file():
            sensorFile = open(sensorPath)
            sensorText = sensorFile.read()
            sensorFile.close()

            tempLine = sensorText.split('\n')[1]
            tempData = tempLine.split(' ')[9]
            temperature = float(tempData[2:])
            temperature = temperature/1000

            self.timestamp = int(timestamp)
            self.temperature = int(temperature)

            #print('Temperature is %.2f on %s' % (temperature, self.id))
            print('INSERT INTO %s (unixtime, temperature) VALUES (%d, %.2f)' % (self.id, self.timestamp, self.temperature))
            #self.log()
```

Maybe I'm just not familiar enough with Python to know which data structures to use, I hope you can help me.

Comment: try tagging this with mysql and MySQLdb, it looks like those are where you need help. The rules are in the database, and run as such. They are not translating into python code (though you could try to do that) so try diving into the MySQLdb library and MySQL documentation

Comment: If you trust your database input, you *could* put normal python code into it that get's `eval`-called with the current sensor inputs and access to functions to call

Comment: Yes, this can be done. But you are essentially inventing your own “DSL” (“Domain-Specific Language”) for encoding the rules and storing them in a database, as well as inventing your own custom interpreter in Python for this language. It may indeed be the right way to solve your problem, but it will involve some work (as well as careful design). What conditions do you need to handle, and what kinds of actions will they invoke?